# How to remove x button in modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there any way to remove the closing button (x) in the upper right corner of a modal? The reason why i need it is that the modal contains a mandatory form and I do not want the user to escape from it.

**Ooops**
I didn't realize the close button was actually explicitly added in the code i pasted

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```

I though it was an attribute of the modal. Sorry

Comment: I got the exact same case with you! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can remove the `close` button markup, and use the `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"` attributes to prevent the user from closing it...

http://www.bootply.com/43VI44Y3lG

Answer (score 13):

Since this is the code for x button:

```
<button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
```

Just use this css:

```
.close {display: none;}
```

Comment: This worked for me!  I wasn't using the complete markup and so this was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 12):

From code of Bottstrap modal window

```
   <div class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Remove the Line from above Code

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```

I think it's Helped you for removing close button

Comment: Your answer worked for me you saved me time sir

Answer (score 3):

I looked for components inside the modal which belongs to `.close` class then set css property to none

id of the modal is `myModalId`

```
function hideCloseButton(){
   // get the close button inside the modal
   $('#myModalId .close').css('display', 'none');
}

// finally call the method
hideCloseButton();
```

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the input type button and the solution work for me, the code removed was:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this `<modal :show-close="false">`

Answer (score 0):

Added this CSS. My modal id is myModal. Class for close button .btn-close. This is for bootstrap 5.

```
  #myModal .btn-close{
         display: none;
     }
```